# Index like iOS contact app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, contacts

I want to create a view like, `iOS` contact app has,

[image]

> Basically i want is, Vertical `ABCDEFG....` which is located on right
>   side of this image,     when user clicks on character `M` i want to
>   get character `M`  How should i achieve this ? is there any iOS
>   control which gives me this `ABCDEF...?

**Thanks in advnace.**

**EDIT**

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[NSArray arrayWithObject:UITableViewIndexSearch] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:
            [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (title == UITableViewIndexSearch)
    {
        CGRect searchBarFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
        [tableView scrollRectToVisible:searchBarFrame animated:YES];

        return -1;
    }
    else {
        UILocalizedIndexedCollation *currentCollation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
        NSLog(@"selected charecter=%ld",(long)[currentCollation sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index]);
        return [currentCollation sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create a custom UITableView with an index or do you just want to present the built in contact picker?

Comment: i dont want to create custom tableview,  i want only ABCDEF... which is located in right side. what is the name of that control ?? is that contact picker ??

Comment: Do you have a table view with your own data in it? Or are you using the contact picker? PLEASE EXPLAIN WHAT YOU WANT TO DO OTHERWISE WE HAVE NO IDEA. The control you are referring to is part of `UITableView` if you don't have a `UITableView` then you can't get this without writing the whole thing yourself from scratch.

Comment: I want highlighted part only `ABCD...` i have tablview but it is custom tableview not a normal plain tableview. is it possible to create same view with with custom tableview ?

Comment: So, when I asked "Do you want to create a custom UITableView with an index" and you said "no" what you actually meant was "yes". Search google for "UITableView index" there are hundreds of examples.

Comment: I am sorry if u got stucked, but actually i was not knowing the name of control.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement these two methods:

```
// return list of section titles to display in section index view (e.g. "ABCD...Z#")
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;                                                    
// tell table which section corresponds to section title/index (e.g. "B",1))
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

with the corresponding data source:

For example, if you have an array with

```
`@"Cat", @"Mouse", @"Dog", @"Horse", @"Duck", @"Monkey"`
```

then you would return and array for `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` as :

```
`@[@"C", @"D", @"H", @"M"]`
```

because `@"Dog"` and `@"Duck"` goes for `@"D"`, `@"Mouse"` and `@"Monkey"` goes for `@"M"` and so on.

And of course, for `sectionForSectionIndexTitle`, you return the corresponding index for that index. (1 for `@"D"`, 3 for `@"M"` etc.)

Comment: i want full `ABCD...` i have to write like this ?? `- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"D",.... nil];
}` and how to fetch selected character ??

Comment: yes, that is correct. For fetching the first characters, you can do it on your own (it's not that hard) or if you already have an `NSArray`, or `NSFetchedResultsController`, you can get them with an `NSPredicate`, though I'm not sure for `NSArray` how it's done, as I don't like this method. I like to do it on my own, to have more control.

Comment: I tried this, i am getting full `ABCDE...`, now when i click on searchicon which is a first character then searchbar is not showing up.... see my **EDIT** in the question

Comment: well the search bar needs to have its own section (and be the first item in your array of indexes as well), and not added as a header view or attached simply to the table view's scroll view. But if you do do this, I think you need to go with `[tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, -44, 320, 1) animated:YES];` or something similar.

Comment: I have not added `serachBar` in first cell, do i need to add ?

Comment: yes, you should. That's what I meant by 'having its own section' :)

Comment: Wow, you really don't need to add a search bar to a cell. The UISearchBar is something that is used separately... never mind...

Comment: What's so `wow` about it ? how do you access it by tapping it on the index if it's not in the table view ? ... sigh ...